# KafkaStreams - recover stream after broker failure

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I've implemented a KafkaStreams app with the following properties

```
application.id = KafkaStreams
application.server = 
bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092,localhost:9093]
buffered.records.per.partition = 1000
cache.max.bytes.buffering = 10485760
client.id = 
commit.interval.ms = 30000
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
default.key.serde = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
default.timestamp.extractor = class org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.FailOnInvalidTimestamp
default.value.serde = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
key.serde = null
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
num.standby.replicas = 0
num.stream.threads = 1
partition.grouper = class org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.DefaultPartitionGrouper
poll.ms = 100
processing.guarantee = at_least_once
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
replication.factor = 1
request.timeout.ms = 40000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
rocksdb.config.setter = null
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
state.cleanup.delay.ms = 600000
state.dir = /tmp/kafka-streams
timestamp.extractor = null
value.serde = null
windowstore.changelog.additional.retention.ms = 86400000
zookeeper.connect =
```

My kafka version is 0.11.0.1. I launched two kafka brokers on localhost:9092 and 9093 respectively. In both brokers default.replication.factor=2 and num.partitions=4 (the rest of configuration properties are default).

My app receives streaming data from a specific topic, makes some transformations and sends data back to another topic. As soon as the second broker is down, it stops receiving data printing the following:

```
INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - Discovered coordinator localhost:9093 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) for group KafkaStreams.
[KafkaStreams-38259122-0ce7-41c3-8df6-7482626fec81-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - Marking the coordinator localhost:9093 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) dead for group KafkaStreams
[KafkaStreams-38259122-0ce7-41c3-8df6-7482626fec81-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - Discovered coordinator localhost:9093 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) for group KafkaStreams.
[KafkaStreams-38259122-0ce7-41c3-8df6-7482626fec81-StreamThread-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Connection to node 2147483646 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | KafkaStreams] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Connection to node 1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

For some reason it doesn't rebalance in order to connect to the first broker. Any suggestions why is this happening?

Comment: How long did you wait? Failover should happen eventually. What are you topic properties (bin/kafka-topic.sh --describe). It might also be, that the second broker cannot take over partition leadership if its not in-sync with the previous leader.

Comment: I waited at least for five minutes. This is my topic properties before the broker failure: 
`Topic: export Partition: 0 Leader: 1 Replicas: 1,0 Isr: 1,0 
 Topic: export Partition: 1 Leader: 0 Replicas: 0,1 Isr: 0,1 
 Topic: export Partition: 2 Leader: 1 Replicas: 1,0 Isr: 1,0 
 Topic: export Partition: 3 Leader: 0 Replicas: 0,1 Isr: 0,1`

After the failure I have the same properties except for Isr and Leader which now contain only 0.

Comment: After an online searching, I get that the failover takes place, but the consumer related to the failed broker doesn't recognize the leader change.

Comment: (1) What is your topic config for min.in.sync.replicas? (2) After failure, all topic now have leader 0 and ISR 0  (just to confirm -- not 100% clear from your comment above)? (3) Consumers can take some time to pick up a leader change -- if they don't, please report to dev@kafka.apache.org and share the consumer and broker logs in debug mode, so dev team can have a look. Thx.

Comment: (1) min.insync.replicas is default 1. (2) All topics in my case is just one topic and yes, it changed leader and ISR to 0. (3) Now I waited more than 5 minutes. I guess it should have done the leader change.

Comment: I agree. Not sure why it does not pick up the new leader. Maybe you can report this to user@kafka.apache.org and also attache Streams and Broker DEBUG level log files to dig into it.

Comment: Any progress with this?

Comment: The solution is located here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167430/kafka-consumer-fails-to-consume-if-first-broker-is-down