# Kafka consumer fails to consume if first broker is down

Tags: apache-kafka, failover, consumer

I'm using latest version of kafka(kafka_2.12-1.0.0.tgz). I have setup simple cluster with 3 brokers(just changed broker.id=1 and listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092 in properties file for each instance).After cluster is up I created topic with the following command

```
./kafka-topics.sh --create    --zookeeper localhost:2181  --replication-factor 3     --partitions 13    --topic demo
```

then start kafka consumer and producers with the following commands

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --topic  demo  --broker-list localhost:9094,localhost:9093,localhost:9092

./kafka-console-consumer.sh --group test --bootstrap-server localhost:9094,localhost:9093,localhost:9092  --topic demo
```

Everything is ok when all brokers are up. But if I kill first(by start order) broker messages are sent to brokers but consumer can not receive any message.Messages are not lost. After starting that broker consumer immediately receives message.

Logs of consumer after shutting down broker instance:

> [2018-01-09 13:39:31,130] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=test] Connection to node 2147483646 could not be established.
>   Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
>   [2018-01-09 13:39:31,132] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=test] Connection to node 1 could not be established. Broker
>   may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
>   [2018-01-09 13:39:31,344] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=test] Connection to node 2147483646 could not be established.
>   Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
>   [2018-01-09 13:39:31,451] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=test] Connection to node 1 could not be established. Broker
>   may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
>   [2018-01-09 13:39:31,848] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=test] Connection to node 2147483646 could not be established.
>   Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
>   [2018-01-09 13:39:31,950] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=test] Connection to node 1 could not be established. Broker
>   may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
>   [2018-01-09 13:39:32,363] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=test] Connection to node 2147483646 could not be established.
>   Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
>   [2018-01-09 13:39:33,092] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=test] Connection to node 2147483646 could not be established.
>   Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
>   [2018-01-09 13:39:34,216] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=test] Connection to node 2147483646 could not be established.
>   Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
>   [2018-01-09 13:39:34,218] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=test] Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets
>   {demo-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3, metadata=''},
>   demo-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3, metadata=''},
>   demo-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2, metadata=''},
>   demo-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2, metadata=''},
>   demo-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1, metadata=''},
>   demo-5=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1, metadata=''},
>   demo-6=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3, metadata=''},
>   demo-7=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2, metadata=''},
>   demo-8=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3, metadata=''},
>   demo-9=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2, metadata=''},
>   demo-10=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3, metadata=''},
>   demo-11=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2, metadata=''},
>   demo-12=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2, metadata=''}} failed: Offset
>   commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing
>   offsets. The underlying error was: The coordinator is not available.
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
>   [2018-01-09 13:39:34,219] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=test] Connection to node 1 could not be established. Broker
>   may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Log of consumer after starting missing broker again:

> [2018-01-09 13:41:21,739] ERROR [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=test] Offset commit failed on partition demo-0 at offset 3:
>   This is not the correct coordinator.
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
>   [2018-01-09 13:41:21,739] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=test] Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets
>   {demo-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3, metadata=''},
>   demo-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3, metadata=''},
>   demo-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2, metadata=''},
>   demo-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2, metadata=''},
>   demo-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1, metadata=''},
>   demo-5=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1, metadata=''},
>   demo-6=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3, metadata=''},
>   demo-7=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2, metadata=''},
>   demo-8=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3, metadata=''},
>   demo-9=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2, metadata=''},
>   demo-10=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3, metadata=''},
>   demo-11=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2, metadata=''},
>   demo-12=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2, metadata=''}} failed: Offset
>   commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing
>   offsets. The underlying error was: This is not the correct
>   coordinator.
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
>   [2018-01-09 13:41:22,353] ERROR [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=test] Offset commit failed on partition demo-0 at offset 3:
>   This is not the correct coordinator.
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
>   [2018-01-09 13:41:22,354] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=test] Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets
>   {demo-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3, metadata=''},
>   demo-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3, metadata=''},
>   demo-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2, metadata=''},
>   demo-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2, metadata=''},
>   demo-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1, metadata=''},
>   demo-5=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1, metadata=''},
>   demo-6=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3, metadata=''},
>   demo-7=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2, metadata=''},
>   demo-8=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3, metadata=''},
>   demo-9=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2, metadata=''},
>   demo-10=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3, metadata=''},
>   demo-11=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3, metadata=''},
>   demo-12=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2, metadata=''}} failed: Offset
>   commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing
>   offsets. The underlying error was: This is not the correct
>   coordinator.
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to check "offsets.topic.replication.factor" in server-*.properties file

For example:

```
############################# Internal Topic Settings       
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics    
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is  recommended for to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
```

http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs

Comment: but how its related to this particular issue? I have the same issue but changing this property doesn't help.

Comment: @MeetJoeBlack Did you restart your cluster after making this change?

Answer (score 0):

Using `KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR` on `yml` file solve this issue.

E.g. Using 2 workers on `docker-swarm`.

```
environment:
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
```